# scrapy shell returns different results and script returns different

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this URL "http://www.funkytrunks.com/715-clearance"

My xpath is as followed,

```
//a[@class="product_img_link"]//@href
```

When i use Scrapy Shell it returns 122 rows and in browser it returned 135 rows. It's quite strange issue. I checked html using `response.body` and saved this to HTML file and open that in browser and ran xpath and it worked perfectly.

Any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Scrapy doesn't parse Javascript so that could be the reason you're getting that mismatch; some Javascript code could be inserting those extra hrefs.

If that's the case - and if those missing hrefs are relevant - you'll need to use [Selenium](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html) or abandon Scrapy altogether and use something like [Phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org), for instance

Comment: That is not the case. There is no Javascript involved.

Comment: Strange... No idea mate, sorry. In any case, you should post more information about your problem.

Comment: If you have Scrapy installed and there you can check using following commands scrapy shell "http://www.funkytrunks.com/715-clearance" and then use len(hxs.select('//a[@class="product_img_link"]//@href')). You will get 122 records and same way try xpath in Chrome or Firefox there you will get 135 records.